# Android List View image view Error?

Tags: android, imageview

In my android application list view there is a image. The imageview is on another layout. i want to change that image to another one through code . when i run the program with the code its getting error..'

Can anyone help me to find the error thank youu ./

I have tried..

```
  Bitmap bImag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tick);
                down.setImageBitmap(bImag);
```

**and this too**

```
myImgView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.monkey);
```

My xml code .. (I used Onclick on the imageview)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/Itemname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="asdas"
        android:layout_weight="0.9"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:onClick="download"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/download" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Java code ..

```
 public void download(View view) {
        String value = getIntent().getExtras().getString("id");
        if (value.equals("Pretham (2016)")) {
            Intent i=new Intent(Song_List.this, MyService.class);
            startService(i);
            Toast.makeText(Song_List.this, "Downloading..........", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Bitmap bImag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tick);
            down.setImageBitmap(bImag);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(Song_List.this, "Downloaded Song.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

my logcat is..

```
Process: com.example.jithin.myapplication, PID: 1539
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5201)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21163)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
```

Comment: what error??pls elaborate

Comment: **Intent intent=getIntent(); String value = intent.getStringExtras("id");** try like this

Comment: @Jithin as you can see, problem is onClick `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick`, paste all onClick code.

Comment: the problem is with the code that i used to replace the image . when i removed the code  (Bitmap bImag = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.tick);
                down.setImageBitmap(bImag); it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The imageView has:

`android:onClick="download"`

Only works if the layout is from Activity setContentView() not from listview or Fragment

You need to add on the adapter:

```
 ImageView img = findViewById(R.id.download);
    img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //CODE on click
        }
    });
```

and remove onclick from xml